# Magento 2.1 and PHP 7.0.8 work extremely slow

Tags: magento2, performance, php-7

I had Magento 2.0.4 instance running on vagrant machine:

- CentOS 6.5
- PHP 7.0.1
- MySQL 5.6.31

I've upgraded to 2.1 with composer but then when I tried to run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I get noticed that PHP version is not supported and needed to upgrade [[release notes]](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.0CE.html#system-requirements). So I've upgraded to PHP 7.0.8 and then my Magento starts to work very slow (about 45 sec for any frontend page). I tried to downgrade Magento to 2.0.4 but still working slow. I assume that is from the PHP version upgrade.

When I turned on caches it works normal.

Did anyone had this issue and know how to resolve it?

Comment: I confirm. Have the same situation with an update two days ago. No solution at the moment. I can even add, that 7.1 is not compatible yet (which already obvious due to Magento 2 requirements)

Comment: something that works really well is to in phpstorm add a filewatcher, and clear the cache when you make changes to the files you are working on (clearout all the var/* folder). That way you can leave the caches on. I found Magento 2 works very poorly without caches and is not even useable.

My filewatcher looks like this:  http://screencast.com/t/NIubvk0kn

and the clearcache.sh script is this:
`/bin/rm -Rf /var/www/html/magento2/var/*`

you can also do something similar with a .bat file if you are in windows

Comment: @KevinJavitz I cleared var folder but this is not the problem. I am pretty sure now that is from the PHP version because it's working normally on PHP 5.6 (same magento instance) and If I switch to PHP 7.0.8 it's ~5 times slower.

Comment: Same here. M 2.1 + PHP 7  is extremely slow, which is ironic. It's even hosted in a monster server with 32gb ram and dual octa-core processors. T_T. Magento 1.9.3 is wayyyyyyyy faster on PHP 5.6 with minimum specs.